# How to draw a rosette?

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I am looking forward to make a rosette using c# graphics...
Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[Rosette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/Academ_rosette.svg/630px-Academ_rosette.svg.png)

Till now i did this:

```
Pen lapsi = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        Rectangle katrori = new Rectangle(250, 200, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori2 = new Rectangle(350, 200, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori3 = new Rectangle(150, 200, 200, 200);

        Rectangle katrori4 = new Rectangle(200, 110, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori5 = new Rectangle(200, 285, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori6 = new Rectangle(295, 110, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori7 = new Rectangle(300, 282, 200, 200);

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori); //kryesor
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori2); //djatht
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori3); //majt
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori4); //nalt-majt
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori5); //posht-majt
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori6); //nalt-djatht
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori7);//posht djatht
```

I have drawn 7 circles so far, but i only want to show the one in the middle containing rossete. How to get rid of those extra lines outside the main circle..
If someone can give me some lines of code and show me how this is done, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: This is a C# question, not a C question. Retagged accordingly.

Comment: accidently pressed enter, ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the rectangle for your center circle and Inflate() it by some percentage.  Next, create a GraphicsPath() and add an ellipse to it using the inflated rectangle via AddEllipse().  Finally, CLIP your graphics surface using SetClip().  This will prevent anything outside that ellipse from being displayed:

```
        Pen lapsi = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        Rectangle katrori = new Rectangle(250, 200, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori2 = new Rectangle(350, 200, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori3 = new Rectangle(150, 200, 200, 200);

        Rectangle katrori4 = new Rectangle(200, 110, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori5 = new Rectangle(200, 285, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori6 = new Rectangle(295, 110, 200, 200);
        Rectangle katrori7 = new Rectangle(300, 282, 200, 200);

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        Rectangle clippingRectangle = new Rectangle(katrori.Location, katrori.Size);
        clippingRectangle.Inflate((int)(katrori.Width * .2), (int)(katrori.Width * .2));
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath GP  = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        GP.AddEllipse(clippingRectangle);
        g.SetClip(GP);

        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori); //kryesor
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori2); //djatht
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori3); //majt
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori4); //nalt-majt
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori5); //posht-majt
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori6); //nalt-djatht
        g.DrawEllipse(lapsi, katrori7);//posht djatht

        g.Dispose();
```

Here's my finished, clipped rosette:
[image: Finished Rosette via Graphics.SetClip()]